# Whether item.recycle method will trigger event receiver?

Tags: development, event-receivers, delete, ssom

When an `item.delete()` methods get called it will trigger the respective item deleting and item deleted event receiver.

Whether this will behave same for the `item.recycle()` method too.

Comment: Attach debugger and see what happen